# How to reshape an array of shape (150,150,3) to an array of shape (1,8192)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have trained a deep learning model as follows, its a classifier base for VGG16.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=4 * 4 * 512),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

1-My model accepts tensors of shape (1,8192) for predictions.

2-I have test images of shape (150,150,3) which are converted to arrays.

3-Now I want a method to convert my (150,150,3) images to tensors of shape (1,8192).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input dimension seems very arbitrary and not suitable to the task. If you are very stubborn to proceed, you could simply cast it to 1d array and resample like this:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy import signal

image = np.random.rand(150,150,3)
image_8192 = signal.resample(image.ravel(), 8192)
```

... but it's a very bad idea. Somewhat smarter would be to more intelligently downsample the image, first by converting it to grayscale and then downsample:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.transform import resize

grayscale = rgb2gray(image) 
grayscale_91pix = resize(image, (91, 91)) # size 8291
image_8192 = signal.resample(grayscale_91pix.ravel(), 8192)
```

It's still not great, but better than the naive approach.

Comment: In both cases it gives following error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'resample'

Comment: @MohammadIbtehaj Sorry, typo. I meant to call `resample` from scipy.

Comment: Thanks mate the bad approach works :-D
But converting to grayscale  raise the following error:

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: @MohammadIbtehaj No prob, I am glad it (partially) worked. Wonder though why are you getting `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'ndim'`? On the code I provided or your own image? With mine `rgb2gray` should work flawlessly.

Comment: Feeding the image to `grayscale = rgb2gray(image)` gives error. But feeding a tensor doesn't. I didn't understand what happened.

Comment: @MohammadIbtehaj The input needs to be a rank 3 tensor, (width, height, no_channels). If you feed it e.g. rank 2 tensor, e.g. (width, height) this won't work as the colour component is not present.

Comment: Feeding image this way to my model results in every prediction to be Dog. Whatever the image is the model just predicts 1. :-(

Comment: Poor results are to be expected. If every prediction says Dog, then most likely you have more problems than just poor (naive) network architecture.